# registering GitHub account in Pycharm not working

Tags: git, github, pycharm

I am trying to register my github account on pycharm. 
I follow the password procedures as stated on https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/registering-github-account-in-pycharm.html

I am doing everything right and I CAN log into my github account using the name psswd combination. So this is not the problem.

This is the message that i get, when I run the "test":

```
Can't login: Connect to api.github.com:443 [api.github.com/192.30.252.124]       failed: connect timed out
```

I am really bad with networks. Also, I am at work, so I'm wondering if pycharm is perhaps under some sort of firewall? the weird thing is that I can use Git Bash command line to work with github repositories, so I can use git, bur for some reason I cannot do it through pycharm.

Also, I'm on windows here.  Thanks.

UPDATE: It looks like everything works fine. The test indicates that things are not working, but I am able to push to github without any problems so far. It's been a couple of days now.

Comment: For simple, You register at GitHub.com website. Then fork, then import a particular Python project to PyCharm, IntelliJ IDEA will require username/password to push to GitHub server.

Comment: That's exactly what I did. And then I got that error.

By the way, I have done this same thing in a few other machines. There's something in particular that is not working this time.